# What are the differences between the following two functions, explaining to a MMA novice?

Tags: programming, coding-style

Obviously the following two functions bring the same results:

```
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
fr[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];

Table[r, {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 1, .25}]
Table[fr[x, y], {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 1, .25}]
```

What are the programming specific advantages of one function compared to the other?

Comment: Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Set and Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/SetDelayed. Look please also into the section "Details" and then go through some examples. You will find all the information there.

Comment: Thank you! The overview "assignments" in the manual, opened my eyes!

Comment: I found this very good explanation: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487)

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't say that `Table[r, {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 1, .25}]` "obviously" produced the same result as the table with `fr[x,y]`. The fact that the table with `r` works is only because of very specific internals of how `Table` works. The form with `fr` should be considered to be the normal way to define a function and `r` should be considered to be a mathematical formula.